# Sencha ExtJS Gridpanel inside Panel does not render once data is set to the GridPanel Store

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a Gridpanel inside a vertical panel so that I can place something underneath the gridpanel. Everything renders no issues until I set the store property on the gridpanel. Then the window just goes white and nothing is rendered. There must be something small I am mising.

```
newWindow = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: 'View Data',
    height: 400,
    width: 600,
    layout: 'fit',
    bodyPadding: 5,
    resizable: false,
    items: 
    [ 
        { xtype:'panel', layout:{ type:'vbox', pack:'center' }, items:
            [
                { xtype: 'gridpanel', height:200, columns: 
                    [
                        { header: 'A', dataIndex: 'a'}, 
                        { header: 'B', dataIndex: 'b' },
                        { header: 'M', dataIndex: 'm' },
                        { header: 'i', dataIndex: 'i' }
                    ], store: store, forceFit: true, border: true
                },
                { xtype:'panel', title: 'Hot Load',  border: true, margin:'5', height:150, width: 500, layout:{ type:'hbox', pack:'center' }, bodyBorder: true, collapsible: true }
            ]           
        }
    ],
    buttons: 
    [
        { text: 'OK' } ,
        { text: 'Cancel' }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an issue with the data in your store in some way - which you don't show in your code here.

I did create a jsFiddle using a store.. If you populate your store with some sample data and still get the rendering issues, I'd start with something similar to what is in this jsFiddle and add the extra formatting/configs to that.

I did remove the extra panel, and jsFiddle doesn't really handle `Ext.window.Window` so I used a panel there just for example.

http://jsfiddle.net/LgyLsmv2/

```
Ext.define('Example', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'a'
    }, {
        name: 'b'
    }, {
        name: 'm'
    }, {
        name: 'i'
    }]
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Example',
    data: [{
        a: 'test A',
        b: 'test B',
        m: 'test M',
        i: 'test I'
    }, {
        a: 'test A',
        b: 'test B',
        m: 'test M',
        i: 'test I'
    }, {
        a: 'test A',
        b: 'test B',
        m: 'test M',
        i: 'test I'
    }]
});

newWindow = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'View Data',
    height: 400,
    width: 600,
    //layout: 'fit',
    //bodyPadding: 5,
    //resizable: false,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'gridpanel',
        //height: 200,
        columns: [{
            header: 'A',
            dataIndex: 'a',
            flex: 1
        }, {
            header: 'B',
            dataIndex: 'b',
            flex: 1
        }, {
            header: 'M',
            dataIndex: 'm',
            flex: 1
        }, {
            header: 'i',
            dataIndex: 'i',
            flex: 1
        }],
        store: store //,
        //forceFit: true,
        //border: true
    }, {
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Hot Load',
        //border: true,
        //margin: '5',
        height: 150,
        width: 500 //,
        //layout: {
            //type: 'hbox',
            //pack: 'center'
        //},
        //bodyBorder: true,
        //collapsible: true
    }],
    buttons: [{
        text: 'OK'
    }, {
        text: 'Cancel'
    }]
});
```